# Tensor multiplication

Tags: matrix, tensors

I have eight Tensors to multiply as follows,

$$P=\sum_{all indices}M_{ijkl}M_{mjkl}M_{inkl}M_{mnkl}X_{kl}Y_{kl}X_{kl}Y_{kl}$$

Each M Matrix is say $2^7\times2^7 \times2^7 \times 2^7$ size. Is there any efficient way to perform this multiplication? Tensor contract even with Active and Inactive fails due to the exceptionally large Tensor(rank 10-12 ) that gets generated in between which requires huge amount of memory.
The greater than 2 repeated indices is not a mistake, it is what it is.

Comment: An explicit $ M $ is appreciated, I guess.

Comment: You can take it to be a completely randomreal matrix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, it is quite feasible. Let $N$ be the tensor dimension, $N=2^7$ in your case. I claim that the computational cost is $\mathcal{O}(N^5)$, which is around $3.2\times 10^{10}$, i.e., the tensor contraction can be computed within 1 minute on a laptop. Observe the following:

1. $M$ can be contracted with $X$ or $Y$ beforehand yielding $A_{ijkl}$, $B_{mjkl}$, $A_{inkl}$ and $B_{mnkl}$. This is just a $\mathcal{O}(N^4)$ operation, use `Table` for that.
2. Consider first the inner sum over $i,j,m,n$. This can be done sequentially via matrix multiplication (use `.` and `Tr`) as follows at the $\mathcal{O}(3 N^3)$ cost

$$T= A.B,\\
T= T.A,\\
T=T.B,\\
x_{kl}=\mathrm{Tr}(T).
$$

3. Finally, one performs the sum $\sum_{kl}x_{kl}$ with the $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ cost (`Sum` or `ParallelSum`).

Total computational cost is $\mathcal{O}(N^5)$. The space requirements are also very modest: one needs to store only 2 additional tensors $A$ and $B$ and a matrix $T$. Total additional storage $N^2(2 N^2+1)$, i.e., $\mathcal{O}(N^4)$.

The mathematica code could be as simple as `A=Table[..]; B=Table[..]; Sum[a=A[[All,All,k,l]]; b=B[[All,All,k,l]]; Tr[a.b.a.b],{k,N},{l,N}]`

Comment: This seems easily achievable thanks. I shall do it and check, shall accept it as an answer once I do it.

Comment: @RoopayanGhosh Have you already checked it?

Comment: Oh thanks for reminding, I did and it worked, accepting the answer. Sorry I forgot

Answer (score 3):

Making the ideas in @yarchik's solution explicit:

using smaller versions of your matrices,

```
t = 4;
M = Array[mm, {t, t, t, t}];
X = Array[xx, {t, t}];
Y = Array[yy, {t, t}];
```

the exact sum you're looking for is

```
S = Sum[M[[i, j, k, l]] M[[m, j, k, l]] M[[i, n, k, l]] M[[m, n, k, l]]
        X[[k, l]] Y[[k, l]] X[[k, l]] Y[[k, l]],
        {i, t}, {j, t}, {k, t}, {l, t}, {m, t}, {n, t}];
```

define intermediates `MX` and `MY`:

```
MX = Transpose[Transpose[M, {3, 4, 1, 2}]*X, {3, 4, 1, 2}];
MY = Transpose[Transpose[M, {3, 4, 1, 2}]*Y, {3, 4, 1, 2}];
```

define an intermediate `A`: this step can probably also be done with a list-processing (linear algebra) operation instead of `Table`; but I can't figure it out right now,

```
A = Table[MX[[All, j, k, l]] . MY[[All, n, k, l]],
          {j, t}, {n, t}, {k, t}, {l, t}];
```

Now the sum is a scalar product:

```
S == Flatten[Transpose[A]] . Flatten[A] // Expand
(*    True    *)
```

Comment: `A` is rank-4 and the whole thing scales as yours, as far as I can see.

Comment: This seems to have same complexity to me as well. Thanks for the explicit answer.

Comment: @Roman Sorry, I misunderstood your method. It became completely clear after you added `All`.